# Adding a counter within Rules

Tags: 7, rules

I have created an endless loop within [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) that will evaluate nodes after they are created and reschedule itself as shown here:
[image: endless loop]

I would like the loop to close after three emails have been sent.  A counter could be added to the action set under "Send Email" then the conditions could include a Data Comparison to see if the counter is less than 3.

I have tried creating fields within the content type that would have the Rule Component increase the counter field by one every time the email section was executed then have a data comparison between the counter field and a Email Max field that had a default value of 3.  I wasn't able to get this to work because the counter would not be increased.

Could this be done with an "Execute Custom PHP Code" action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going off memory here:

For both if and else, Add Action >> Set a Data Value >> node:field-email-max >> OFFSET: +1  `(To get the offset, you will have to click the switch data selection button)`

[image]

For both if and else >> Add Conditional >> Data Comparison >> node:field-email-max >> Less than 3

Comment: Going with the offset idea, Rules didn't let me have an offset with direct input as shown here [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/ORYrhWe.png).  So I needed to use data selection to have the offset shown here [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/9g8SO3u.png).  Then to have the the "max" field increase by one for each email, the counter feilded needed to increase as well since "max" was getting set to it.  So both are getting set equal to each other then increased by one as shown here: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/VA0sagW.png).  Which is an interesting way to do it but I guess it works. Would using PHP be cleaner?

Comment: [like I mention in my answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pp78D.jpg) in [Set Data Value](http://i.imgur.com/ORYrhWe.png) you need to click on the Switch to data selection button

Comment: Great I appreciate your time No Sssweat!

Comment: Interesting ... I didn't know/realize this about the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module !

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens hehe yeah hidden trick.

Comment: @NoSssweat For *some* (hm, hm) reason, my upvote from before (around March 31, 2016?) no longer shows up here ... So let me retry and see if it ever disappears again ...